# Prove $\neg\exists x \neg P(x)$ is a logical consequence of $\forall x P(x)$

Tags: logic, proof-writing, quantifiers

How would you prove that 2. is a logical consequence of 1. using [a Fitch style proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitch-style_calculus)?

1. $\forall x P(x)$
2. $\neg\exists x \neg P(x)$

Comment: You're trying to obtain a statement where the main connective is a negation, yes?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

This was done using Fitch. You need to start first by assuming that what you want to prove is false. From here you can perform existential elimination, which will eventually entail a contradiction. This will then allow you to reject your assumption, thus proving your conclusion.